# Should I Log or not?

Tags: language-agnostic, logging

I am sure lots of you had this debate: What to write or not to the application log file.

I am not talking about the trivial error exception which we surely log inside the catch clauses.

Let's say we have a standart application which is connecting to database doing some selects.

we have a Dao object which each method in it wrapping  a select query.

I would like to have your suggesations. Should I log every  entrance and exit before I execute any selection? Should I log the result?

what about logging the error stacktrace? I find it very messy and overloading the log file.

could anyone recommend me on a good article in this subject(not necessary about logging database executions but generally)?

Thanks,

ray.

Comment: I've removed the C# and Java tags, as your question is largely language agnostic.

Comment: "what about logging the error stacktrace? I find it very messy and overloading the log file" - Aren't these precisely the things you want to identify and fix?

Comment: You can create more than one log file. I have over 20 ;)  One for errors and general execution, you could have one for queries and results etc.

Comment: If you don't like errors in your logs, I suggest you fix the code so you don't get errors in your logs. ;)

Comment: It's not about having the errors in my logs.. it's about what to have and what not to have in my logs except of the errors! I saw sometimes programmers write the whole flow in the log(debug) and it overhead the logs make it  very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging means exacly that: taking notes when something happens. So you need to understand your needs as developer, and the needs of your customers. In both cases, try to figure out what do you need to accomplish your task.

As a developer, you should decide what level of confidence do you have with your software: if it is fully tested and debugged, then you could not log anything at all and just try to trace crashes. If on the other hand you are doing debug, you could need more detail. And in general, you should leave the possibility to turn logging off when confidence increases, and turning it on when thngs start to fail, possibly through a configuration setting. When you need to decide what to log, ask yourself: if it crashed, will this information help me identify the problem or will it be just noise?

For you customers, it depends. On a shared system for example, it's good to know who did what, so it happens to me to log actions that customers do. You should agree that with your customer.

Comment: I saw a methodology when programmers debug each entrance and exit of a method. What do you think about that?

Comment: Everything depends on the purpose. This technique is a bit "extreme": you are doing a full trace of your application and can potentially produce enormous data quantities. But if your app misbehaves, and you can't find a way to reproduce it, and you can't use a debugger, this could be your last resort.

Comment: It's called instrumentation and can be very useful to debug many problems where simply stepping through the code would change the timings and therefore the behavior (threads) or would be too cumbersome or timeconsuming. The latter especially being the case in framework code which will be hit very often but mostly for instances unrelated to the problem. When the instrumentation logging indents on each "enter" and outdents on each exit, problems with call order, thread contention and complex unwanted recursion become a lot more visible.

Answer (score 0):

don't log more than necessary.

more detailed explanation here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/the-problem-with-logging.html

cheers

Answer (score 0):

that's why you have various log levels. the purely informational stuff you log at LOG_INFO and the debugging stuff you log at LOG_DEBUG. what actually gets logged is up to the user.